# Where can I download the image or video stimuli for the visual coding experiments (allen-sdk)?

Tags: allen-sdk

I am trying to download the images or videos that were used for the visual coding experiments of the Allen institute Brain observatory.

I did follow the tutorials and successfully found the spikes and all sorts of meta data, but I did not find any resource to get the images or videos stimuli.

Specifically, I am looking for the drifting grating videos, the videos of natural movies or the images of natural scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on the Allen Institute Forum:
https://community.brain-map.org/t/how-can-i-generate-visual-stimuli-like-those-used-in-the-brain-observatory/33

This second link provides some code to extract the stimuli:
http://alleninstitute.github.io/AllenSDK/_static/examples/nb/brain_observatory_stimuli.html